# 80's (or earlier) short stories book: tiny visitors in a house inside a house, horses appearing upon wishes, and a story about getting lighter

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I read a book of short stories when I was a kid or pre-teen in the 80's that included a story about a man who has a small house inside his house (think doll house/birdhouse) and he gets tiny visitors which he never can catch a glimpse of. He tries to and it ends up driving them away.

Another of the story is about a family on a farm? Which ends​ up getting horses every time they make a wish and they get out of control.

One more that I remember sounds like a Lovecraft story about a man who wants to be "lighter" he doesn't lose weight but he starts to float away. I do not know if it's the same as the Lovecraft story. I don't think so. I'd have to read it to be sure.

The stories were in a big hardback book that I had so many years ago but I'd love to know what it was!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Please check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking story-id questions to see if they help you remember anything else to [edit] into your question.  Do you remember anything about the cover or how the book looked?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first story is probably "Housing Problem" by Henry Kuttner and C.L. Moore, and the third sounds like "The Truth About Pyecraft" by H. G. Wells.  (I recognized both from having read them.)  An older "big hardback" that contains both of those stories is [ALFRED HITCHCOCK'S GHOSTLY GALLERY](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?524924) from 1962:

[image: book cover, creeped kid hiding behind a bed sheet]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a great start.  If you could add a few details of the stories you've matched to make it clear that they match the question, that would be excellent.

Comment: And the story about a bunch of horses is "The Wonderful Day" by Robert Arthur.  A kid makes a wish and suddenly the idioms his parents use start being true.  "If wishes were horses" becomes an endless supply of horses for the person always making wishes.  The town gossip suddenly literally has a tongue that flaps at both ends...

Comment: I had this collection in the 70s, I think you're right.

Comment: I started by searching for stories with "If Wishes Were Horses" as the title.  This was clearly the wrong approach...

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!! IT IS DEFINITELY the Alfred Hitchcock's Ghostly Gallery! I recognized the cover! I found it used on Amazon for $6 and its en route! I've been looking for this for 30 years! Again, THANK YOU!